# Entity Framework connection error after uploading to Hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I built Application using asp.net and entityframework for database 
here is my connectionstring of context class

```
<add name="EStringspbcontext" connectionString="Connection string: Data Source=localhost;
Initial Catalog=EStringspb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sqladmin;Connect Timeout=15;
Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework;Persist Security Info = True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

when i try to login it throws the error

It works on Local Machine but when we uploaded on hosting server it throws the following error

> "This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable
>   to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original
>   database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed
>   from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection."

here is my login code

```
string emailid ="johnddoe@gmail.com";
UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
                using (EStringspbcontext db = new EStringspbcontext())
                {                        
                    var objuser = (from obj in db.Users where obj.EmailId == emailid  select obj).SingleOrDefault();
                    user = (UserEntity)objuser;
                    db.Dispose();
                }
                    if (user.Password == txtadminPassword.Value)
                    {
                        //if (user.OnlineStatus == false)
                        //{
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Usersdetails set OnlineStatus = '" + true + "' where EmailId ='" + user.EmailId.ToString() + "'", con))
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update connection string as per your hosting server..like you have to change server.

```
<add name="EStringspbcontext" connectionString="Server=ipofserver;initial catalog=EStringspb;Trusted_Connection = True ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: I have updated the Connection string but still same Error

Comment: You can get exact connection string from your hosting server.and put that connection string in your code.

Answer (score 1):

i forgot to add Password in Connection String  after adding Password=abc to my connection string it worked

here is that connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="democontext" connectionString="Server=server_name;Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user_id;Password=password;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Persist Security Info = True;Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```